# Get the language of an excel instance in python

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings

I set a format using xlwings `ws.range('A1').number_format = '#.0;[Red]-#.0'` but one of the user has a french Excel and there is an error because of `[Red]`. I have to add a condition based on Excel language, for French Excel instances it must be `[Rouge]`.

Here is my question, do you know how I can get the language of an Excel instance in python (pywin32 / xlwings) ?

In VBA, the following code will return 1 for English Excel and 33 for French Excel:

```
Application.International(xlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode)
```

But I can't manage to get the python equivalent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`wb.app.api.International` returns a tuple with index 0 being 1 or 33 depending on the language.

Answer (score 0):

As asked, the Python equivalent to

```
Application.International(xlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode)
```

would be something like (wb being an `xlwings.Workbook` instance):

```
from xlwings.constants import ApplicationInternational
int_constants = wb.app.api.International
country_code = int_constants[ApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode]
```

The class [ApplicationInternational](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/33fdb5b21a970f72ec455fb08ce56de9c67fc449/xlwings/constants.py#L241) defines the indices you can use to retrieve the respective properties of the International class, as done above. From experience sometimes you need to subtract 1 from these values.

I don't have a lot of experience with specifying colours, but it's probably possible to specify the colour in RGB (it seems to be [possible in VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/excel-formatting/color-reference-for-color-index/#:%7E:text=RGB%20stands%20for%20Red%20Green,255%20for%20each%20color%20code.&text=Above%20we%27ve%20set%20Red,%3D%200%20(min%20value).)). This way you can skip the locale part altogether (and you could use something like [xlwings.constants.RgbColor.rgbRed](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/33fdb5b21a970f72ec455fb08ce56de9c67fc449/xlwings/constants.py#L2549) if you're feeling fancy)